# power shell not null check in if statement

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Am new in powershell script.Am trying to check an if statement having array index is null then control move to else part i tried some ways but not working

code

```
if(-not $node[$i] -ne $null ){

   }else {
      # do something
   }
```

How the control move to else part when the $node[$i] is null.
Above case,getting an error

[image]

Comment: I think you need to test '$node' itself for a null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot index into a null array.

...is telling you that `$node` is null, *not* that `$node[$i]` is null. Try this:

```
if ($node -ne $null) {
    if ($node[$i] -ne $null) {
        # All good; do something interesting.
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. You can make the solution more concise with `-and`; also, it's a good habit to form in PowerShell to use `$null` as the _LHS_ in `-eq` / `-ne` comparisons -  e.g.,`$null -eq $var` instead of `$var -eq $null` - because if the LHS happens to be an _array_, the RHS value acts a _filter_ rather than returning a Boolean. Therefore: `if ($null -ne $node -and $null -ne $node[$i]) { ...`